# How can I do a sum of count based on year, month, day

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table (made using rollups) with the following columns:

customer varchar(255), year int, month int, day int, count int

For each company, their sales for each day are recorded in the rolled up table. Given a company name, start date, and end date, how can I sum the counts between and including those dates. I can separate the input parameters into start_year, end_year, start_month, end_month, start_date, and end_date. I'm able to get the count for a company only using the years, but I don't know how to drill it down to months and days. Because if the start_year is 2020 and the end_year is 2022, I can't just put a condition for start_month >=3 because i want to include january and february of 2021.

Comment: Please post table structure, what you tried, data you have and expected output you would like  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You can rebuild date from its parts and use date comparison opers.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the columns into a date and compare that.

In Redshift, use the `to_date()` function

```
select
    sum(count)
from mytable
where to_date (year || '-' || month || '-' || day, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
  between mystartdate and myenddate
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using postgres on aws redshift, which doesn't seem to have this function.